# "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'" when running lambda function written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently I am writing a lambda function to connect to RDS Aurora cluster.

The following code represent my lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let connection;
    try {
        connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'your-rds-endpoint',
            user: 'your-username',
            password: 'your-password',
            database: 'your-database'
        });
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM your_table');
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(rows)
        };
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Error: ' + err
            })
        };
    } finally {
        if (connection) connection.end();
    } };
```

I keep getting: "Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'", although I have installed mysql2 library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)

The Nodejs version is 18 and here is my config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "rootDir":"src/lambda",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out",
    "lib",
    "bin",
    "test",
    "constants"
  ]
}
```

Comment: First thing is that If you have installed the module then it should be in your "package.json".
Try running the function locally, and if it is working properly then make sure to add your node_modules in the zip you are uploading to lambda/S3.
And also check whether you using the module correctly or not.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thanks for the help